# React MUI v4 switch changes state for a second during render process

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

As you can see this is one react mui v4 switch that has one label and one textbox.
When i update the value of the textbox it will fire an api and once it resolves react will update the state.
But for a sec we can see the switch becoming true and then reverting back to the prev value it had.
Is this a MUI bug or react is doing something here?
I am lost, went through the code multiple time but just couldnt figure it out properly.
Maybe someone from you will help?

The codebase is very big, It is not possible to add it here. So instead i will add the switch that will render this part.

```
<div>
                    <PrimarySwitch
                      data-id={`${participantId}-checkoutAdminOption`}
                      checked={checkoutAdminOption.autoCheckoutEnabled}
                      onChange={(_, checked) => {
                        onChangeCheckoutOption(participantId, 'autoCheckoutEnabled', checked);
                      }}
                    />
                    <span className="px-text">Allow Auto-Checkout for this group</span>
                  </div>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]